# How to Get pipeline_id from DeltaLiveTables (Databricks) in synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-synapse, delta-live-tables

I have a pipeline_name of DeltaLiveTables (DLT) , I need to get Pipeline_id for the DLT using synapse ? Which activity can be used for it in synapse for getting it ?

I tried to use a web activity to trigger a DLT but i had to explicitly pass pipeline_id to run it. Now i am looking to get pipeline_id with pipleine_name in shell script , i am looking to get same pipeline_id using Synapse or ADF

Below is the code

````
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($r)) {
    Write-Host 'Creating pipeline as it does not exist'
    $r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "${pl_uri}" -Method Post -Headers $headers -InFile "${f}"
    Write-Host "$r"
}
else {
    $pipeline_id = $r.statuses[0].**pipeline_id**
    Write-Host "Updating existing pipeline (Pipeline id - $pipeline_id)"
    $r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "${pl_uri}/${pipeline_id}" -Method Put -Headers $headers -InFile "${f}"
    Write-Host "Done"
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use below api to list the pipelines in your workspace and filter it with name to get pipeline id you want.
Refer this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/pipelines/listpipelines) for more about listing the pipelines.

Follow below steps to get pipeline id.

Create below variable in pipeline.

[image]

Next, create a web activity with following configurations.
**URL** : `https://adb-<your_host>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/pipelines`
**Method** : `GET`
**Headers** : `Authorization` and value is `Bearer dapi<your_token>`

[image]

Next, loop through all the results and check for pipeline name match.

Add **ForEach** activity with the results got from web activity.

```
@activity('Web1').output.statuses
```

[image]

and inside that add **If Condition** activity.

[image]

In **If Condition** activity add below details.

**Expression**: `@equals(item().name, variables('pipeline_name'))`

Here, `variables('pipeline_name')` is you pipeline name stored in pipeline variables.

If the condition is `True` add **Set variable** activity for pipeline id and if it is `False` pipelined id will be `empty` as we set in default.

[image]

In **Set variable** activity store the pipeline id and you can use it for triggering the pipeline in further activities.

**Value** : `@item().pipeline_id`

[image]

Output:

[image]